# passing variables from a protected function to a public function inside the same class in php

Tags: php, variables

I have a class and two functions inside it as follows:

```
class MyClassName
{
    protected function myFunction1()
    {
        // some code here
        return $something;
    }
    public function myFunction2()
    {
        // some code here
        return $somethingElse;
    }
}
```

What I need to do is define a variable in myFunction1() and then use it in myFunction2(). What is the best practice to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "define" and "pass"? What's wrong with calling `$this->myFunction2($parameter)` in `myFunction1` ?

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it is public, protected or private though.

Comment: the best practice is define such variable as property

Comment: Create a field in the class and then use that in both of your functions using `$this->` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyClassName
{
    public $var = 0;
    protected function myFunction1()
    {
        // some code here
        $this->var = ...;
        return $something;
    }
    public function myFunction2()
    {
        // some code here
        echo $this->var;
        return $somethingElse;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually vars should be defined out of the function and then set a value. Then can be modified over all the script, by doing this->var

Comment: Thanks that's what I finally did.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a class property

```
class MyClassName
{
    private $property;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->myFunction1();
    }

    protected function myFunction1()
    {
        // some code here
        $this->property = 'an apple';
    }
    public function myFunction2()
    {
        // some code here
        return $this->property;
    }
}
```

Now test it:

```
$my_class = new MyClassName();
$something = $my_class->myFunction2();
echo $something;
```

Comment: Thanks this is a very good solution, but for my special case does not work for me.